# QueryableStoreRegistry is used to query state store in spring cloud stream, I am not sure if it could query remote ones?

Tags: spring-cloud-stream

In kafka document, it said that we could query state store via RPC. So I am not sure if QueryableStoreRegistry could get the same functionality in spring cloud stream.

Answer (score 1):

This is an area where we are looking to improve in the next version of the Spring Cloud Stream binder. Please see [this issue](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka/issues/656).